# MySQL query returning unknown values

Tags: mysql, sql

first of all this is a little bit complicated to explain.

I'm having issues with only one CONCAT. The following query returns 'Locale' values that doesn't exist in table.

```
SELECT client.description, client.name, loc.description
FROM clients AS client
LEFT JOIN FromWhere AS from ON from.id = client.id_from
LEFT JOIN locale AS loc ON loc.id = from.id_loc
client.description LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
AND IFNULL(client.name, '') LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
AND IFNULL(loc.description, '') LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')
GROUP BY client.id
ORDER BY client.id DESC
```

My table reproduces the following (CORRECT):

```
-description-------name----------locale
-------------------------------------------
 Dude...         Testing         Paris
 No stop         Another         null
 Representing    null            null
 stackover       OneMore         London
```

With the code MySQL above, if I change to what I want I got this strange results:

```
SELECT client.description, client.name, loc.description
FROM clients AS client
LEFT JOIN FromWhere AS from ON from.id = client.id_from
LEFT JOIN locale AS loc ON loc.id = from.id_loc
client.description LIKE CONCAT('%', 'stackover', '%') 
AND IFNULL(client.name, '') LIKE CONCAT('%', 'OneMore', '%') 
AND IFNULL(loc.description, '') LIKE CONCAT('%', 'OK', '%')
GROUP BY client.id
ORDER BY client.id DESC



   -description-------name----------locale
   -------------------------------------------
     stackover       OneMore         OK
```

As you see, "Locale" -> OK doesn't exist..
This happens to a few values..and I can't figure out the connection between them.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should put backticks around the alias `from` since it is a keyword. You are also missing a boolean operator (or possible a WHERE) between `ON loc.id = from.id_loc` and `client.description LIKE CONCAT('%', 'stackover', '%') `

Comment: I do have the second operator..passing to here and adapt so you guys could understand I, somehow, forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where the problem is

I have recreated your tables in the following SQL Fiddle, and things seem to be working fine.

Please comment/uncomment the filter on location description and check.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f6a4c/8

Can you please update the fiddle with the specific scenario, in case this is not satisfactory.

Comment: The problem of showing you is that I have tons of records (because it joins with a table which has the postalcodes..) Although I think I've accomplish to make the same error on SQLFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d18b/9

I've tried to adapt, so you could understand +/- the tables I have and fields.

Comment: Btw, if I do remove the "GROUP BY" from my original code, I get thousands of records duplicated that doesn't exist with the same id!!

Comment: You are using GROUP BY wrongly. The reason you have duplicate records is because you have same id_town used for different towns. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc94d/1.

Comment: Yes. I came to the same conclusion than you..although I kind of need that. The .CSV file I receive with all towns and cities has the value of Towns that belongs to Cities. So the table is kind of: Town 1, Town 2, Town 3 belongs to City A :: Town 1, Town 2, Town 3 belongs to City B. etc..is anything I can do?

Comment: Thanks, solved with your help. I created another table called town_rel to make the relations between the tables and it's working fine now.